# What does "risk divides too wide for any bridge" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning, sentence-meaning

I read a sentence "China should re-learn Deng’s self-knowledge, or risk divides too wide for any bridge." Can you help explain the meaning of "risk divides too wide for any bridge" and show where the definition is? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here, **divides** is a noun and **risk** is the verb.

From Collins thesaurus via [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Divide), synonyms for a divide include:

> breach, gulf, gap

Division in a country is often a source of conflict. Here, the risk is "wide divides" in China, and the author emphasise how wide these are by saying they are too wide for any bridge.

As to why the author used **divides** rather than **division**, I think that’s to emphasise multiple, distinct, countable gaps or cracks in Chinese society, rather than a single division.

Comment: excellent answer.